# Error when running webpack script for simple project

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

When I run the script for "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js", I get this error:

Error: For the selected environment is no default script chunk format available:
JSONP Array push can be chosen when 'document' or 'importScripts' is available.
CommonJs exports can be chosen when 'require' or node builtins are available.
Make sure that your 'browserslist' includes only platforms that support these features or select an appropriate 'target' to allow selecting a chunk format by default. Alternatively specify the 'output.chunkFormat' directly.

What is this error? These are the files in my project directory:

```
index.html 

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/main.css" />
  <title>Project Name</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
package.json

{
  "name": "js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Browser 2D game ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "webpack:watch": "webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js",
    "webpack:build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js  --optimize-minimize"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.42.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.56.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

```
postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
};
```

```
webpack.common.js

const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const outputDir = "./dist";

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.js"), 
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDir),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: "/dist/",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"], // if we were using React.js, we would include ".jsx"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // if we were using React.js, we would use \.jsx?$/
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
          }, // if we were using React.js, we would include "react"
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              // you can specify a publicPath here
              // by default it uses publicPath in webpackOptions.output
              publicPath: "../",
            },
          },
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              // you can specify a publicPath here
              // by default it uses publicPath in webpackOptions.output
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "images/",
              publicPath: "images/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ca]ss/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              // you can specify a publicPath here
              // by default it uses publicPath in webpackOptions.output
              publicPath: "../",
            },
          },
          "css-loader",
          "resolve-url-loader",
          {
            loader: "sass-loader", 
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass')
            }
          },
          "postcss-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // all options are optional
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
      ignoreOrder: false, // Enable to remove warnings about conflicting order
    }),
    require("autoprefixer"),
  ],
};
```

```
webpack.dev.js

const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./",
    watchContentBase: true,
    open: true, // use "chrome" for PC
  },
});
```

```
webpack.prod.js

const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./",
    watchContentBase: true,
    open: true, // use "chrome" for PC
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you tried removing any mention of node from your browserslist entry in package.json? I had a similar problem and that seemed to work for me.

Comment: @JulianJohannesen can you make your comment an answer? It seems to work for lots of people (including me).

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried removing any mention of node from your browserslist entry in package.json? I had a similar problem and that seemed to work for me.

Comment: @leep can you please mark that answer as a solution? It seems to be the right answer.

Answer (score 8):

Removing `"maintained node versions"` from browserlists also worked for us.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem before. You can resolve this by adding a `target` attribute. Because JavaScript can be written for both server (Node) and browser (ES6), webpack offers multiple deployment targets that you can set in your webpack. You can split up the webpack configuration and have a separate webpack config for both `server` and  `client`.

For e.g., if you're using **React** for your front end and **Node** for your backend, you can write `target: 'web'` and `target: 'node'` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the object **browserslist** or replace with this:

```
"browserslist": {
"production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
```

}